# FBSDKShareAPI share not visible on test user

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

So, I'm using Facebook share sdk on iOS and just want to share example stuff via test user. I'm logged in with permissions:

```
    loginButton.publishPermissions = ["publish_actions"]
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_likes"]
```

And I'm making share like this:

```
        let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
        
        action.actionType = "og.likes"
        action.setString("http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791", forKey: "object")
        
        let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
        content.action = action
        content.previewPropertyName = "object"
        
        let shareAPI = FBSDKShareAPI()
        shareAPI.delegate = self
        shareAPI.shareContent = content
        let shared = shareAPI.share()
        
        print("shared: \(shared)")
```

I'm getting following result:

> shared: true
>
> didCompleteWithResults [postId: 122321171486204,
> completionGesture: post]

Looks like it's working, right? But then I log in that account and cannot see a thing. It's stated: "No posts to see". Also this account has friends and they cannot see anything too.

Why is that so?

Comment: Is it in the activity log? Not everything goes into newsfeed or timeline.

Comment: Yes! It's there! Thanks! I totally raged, because I couldn't find it anywhere. But that's strange I can only see this in activities, why other accounts (friends) cannot see it?